# Linux - How to open a console and display command results on startup?

Tags: linux, scripting, shell, startup, command

I have a Linux server with a screen always displaying the end of a very usefull file.

How could I automatically enter a shell and display the end of this file when the server starts?

I'd like to do absolutely nothing and see the result of
    tail -fn 50 /very/usefull/file

Comment: Just add to your shell's config line that lauch `tail -Fn 50 /file` After login you'll get not a command interpreter prompt but 50 lines of tail.

Comment: Could you please mention the distro you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned what distribution you are using, so Its difficult to give exact instructions. However as an example, I use Gentoo, and place my tail command in /etc/local.d/tailfile.start
Gentoo executes any file in /etc/local.d/ that has a .start extension when the system boots, and the output is displayed just before the login prompt. I imagine there is an equivalent file for the distribution you are using.